# MS Teams | Microsoft bot framework - Returns 502 error on task/fetch

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have an MS Teams adapter written using the botframeworks sdk v4 for node js which works perfectly for normal conversations. But when I try to do a task/fetch, it returns an error message "Unable to reach app. Please try again." on the task module popup

[image]

I can see from the inspector that it returns 502 response for the request to invoke the task module

[image]

The task module returns a simple adaptive card and I can see that I get a callback on my handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch function from the logs

[image]

The adapter runs on a docker container with an nginx proxy and the nginx logs shows that, it returns a 200 response whenever I click on the task module launch button

I have a similar setup in my dev and taskmodule works perfect there

Any help is highly appreciated

**Update**

I have tried hardcoding the adaptive card. That doesnt help either

[image]

Comment: Could you please check if the final response being sent is similar to the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots#invoking-a-task-module-via-taskfetch)? Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes it is. Also the same is working in my dev. There is no errors in the node console

Comment: Could you please share your app manifest with us?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6cxJCbyx this is how my manifest looks like

Comment: We would need the entire manifest(including the id) to test it on our side. Please share it to microsoftteamsdevATmicrosoft.com if you do not want to share it publicly.

Comment: I have sent the manifest file in email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually it was found that there was a problem with one of the csp headers and microsoft was not happy about it.

I removed the CSP headers and the taskmodule started working

Thanks to @gousia-msft for your help in debugging the issue